# barcode scanning algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, barcode

i cant solve the problem, that the following code is showing ...

```
clear
I=imread('barcode.jpg');%read image from drive;
I=im2bw(I);             
imshow(I);  
hold on;
[x,y]=ginput(2);        %get data from click mouse
u1=x(1);
u2=y(1);
v1=x(2);
v2=y(2);
line(x,y);              %paint the line between 2 point at click mouse
a = [u1:1:v1];          %find out function line between 2 point
if (u1~=v1) & (u2~=v2)
    g = round(((v2-u2)/(v1-u1))*a + u2 -(u1/(v1-u1)));
elseif (u1==v1)
    a = u1;
end                      
i=1;                    %find the value each pixel that the line go through
h=v1-u1+1;
b=[1:1:h];
for a=u1:v1
    if (I(g,a)==0)
        b(i)=1;
        i=i+1;
    elseif (I(g,a)==1)
        b(i)=0;
        i=i+1;
    end
end
c=b
i=1;                %find number pixels of each line in barcode picture;
s=[1:1:60];
for k=1:60
    j=0;
    if c(i)==0
        while (c(i)==0)&(i<=h)
            j=j+1;
            i=i+1;
            s(k)=j;
        end
    elseif c(i)==1
        while (c(i)==1)&(i<=h)
            j=j+1;
            i=i+1;
            s(k)=j;
        end
    end
end
mau=s(2);       %the first line is the sample for barcode,in another line is ratio with this
q=s./mau;
p=round(q);     
doc1=[1:1:6];   %decode 
k=1;
for i=5:4:25
    if (p(i)==3)& (p(i+1)==2) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==1)
        doc1(k)=0
    elseif (p(i)==2)& (p(i+1)==2) &(p(i+2)==2) &(p(i+3)==1)
        doc1(k)=1  
    elseif (p(i)==2)& (p(i+1)==1) &(p(i+2)==2) &(p(i+3)==2)
        doc1(k)=2
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==4) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==1)
        doc1(k)=3
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==1) &(p(i+2)==3) &(p(i+3)==2)
        doc1(k)=4
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==2) &(p(i+2)==3) &(p(i+3)==1)
        doc1(k)=5
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==1) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==4)
        doc1(k)=6
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==3) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==2)
        doc1(k)=7
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==2) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==3)
        doc1(k)=8
    elseif (p(i)==3)& (p(i+1)==1) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==2)
        doc1(k)=9
    end
    k=k+1;
end
doc2=[1:1:6];
k=1;
for i=34:4:54
    if (p(i)==3)& (p(i+1)==2) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==1)
        doc2(k)=0
    elseif (p(i)==2)& (p(i+1)==2) &(p(i+2)==2) &(p(i+3)==1)
        doc2(k)=1  
    elseif (p(i)==2)& (p(i+1)==1) &(p(i+2)==2) &(p(i+3)==2)
        doc2(k)=2
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==4) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==1)
        doc2(k)=3
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==1) &(p(i+2)==3) &(p(i+3)==2)
        doc2(k)=4
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==2) &(p(i+2)==3) &(p(i+3)==1)
        doc2(k)=5
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==1) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==4)
        doc2(k)=6
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==3) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==2)
        doc2(k)=7
    elseif (p(i)==1)& (p(i+1)==2) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==3)
        doc2(k)=8
    elseif (p(i)==3)& (p(i+1)==1) &(p(i+2)==1) &(p(i+3)==2)
        doc2(k)=9
    end
    k=k+1;
end
```

the error message is ...

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

```
Error in runprogram (line 22)
if (I(g,a)==0)
```

also any suggestion for simplifying the code for barcode detection?

Comment: Immediately before the id statement on line 22, print the values of g and a.  One of them is probably either less than 1, or not a round number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following lines at the beginning of the program

```
u1=x(1);
u2=y(1);
v1=x(2);
v2=y(2);
```

to this:

```
u1=round(x(1));
u2=round(y(1));
v1=round(x(2));
v2=round(y(2));
```

Things should work now.

HT @arr_sea

One minor simplification is to change the k=1:60 loop to be as follows:

```
for k=1:60          % can have up to 60 lines?
    j=0;
    curr = c(i);
    while (c(i)==curr)&(i<=h) % h is x length of barcode
        j=j+1;
        i=i+1;
    end
    s(k)=j;
end
```

**Edit:**

(1) The numeric translation of the barcode is `[doc1 doc2]`

Comment: thank u for the help .... 
can u also tell me what should be done to show the outputs for only the barcode numbers. Here the output displays all the doc1(k) & doc2(k) numbers but i need to show only the barcode numbers.

also will this algorithm work, if Hough transform & sub-pixel edge detection are applied for image(input) processing.

Comment: Please see my appended comment on how to retrieve the numeric code derived from the barcode. I imagine that edge detection could be useful in particular circumstances prior to conversion into a B&W image, but I am not an expert in the field. I would refer to your prior post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783752/barcode-detection-using-hough-transform-edge-detection?rq=1 or post a new more specific question after you've experimented with these techniques